# How to pass email as a search parameter in symfony 2 route

Tags: symfony

I want to add search with email functionality in my symfony api. I have added function in my controller,but not able to set up route for it.

Let me know how I can pass email as a parameter in symfony2 as get request.

Comment: possibly a duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590929/symfony-email-address-as-request-parameter

Comment: I have used regular expression is failed. I am not sure what to add in requirement as parameter for email. I have tried above link as well but its failing as no route set up.